# Parse attribute data of certain HTML element

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have an HTML page which contains this:

```
<meta property="image" content="http://example.com/example.jpg" />
```

How can I use PHP to reach that "meta property" and get the image URL from "content"?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you tried so far? If it is a string, then you can use regular expression. If this is a rendered page, you need to use javascript and regexp to get that string.

Comment: You can't. The html is client side and PHP server side. What do you actually want to do? When do you want to get the value in php? When the page refreshes or navigates?

Comment: Do you actually grab/scrape content from some site, and want to get image url? Please provide more data, whole context...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working live: http://codepad.org/ggUwL06F

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<meta property="image" content="http://example.com/example.jpg" />');

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

foreach($metas as $meta){

   if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'image') { 
        $meta_image = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        break;
   }

}

echo $meta_image;
```

Do not use regex to parse HTML. Also as @Kiwi1 pointed out you can use the PHP built-in function `get_meta_tags()`. Altho I prefer to use DOM to parse HTML even for simple stuff.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a function that extracts all meta tag content attributes from a URL. Look for it at the PHP docs.

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.url.com/');
```